# Timer in Javascript while functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I have this code:

```
 input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode === 13 && input.value) {
    sendText(input.value);
    var response = responseChat(input.value, 'user');
    insertResponse(response);
    input.value = '';   
  }
});
```

In this code, the client types some words to send to app web. So, I need when, the client not type and send some, the page sends a message of: "You are not work!!"

I create this function with setTimeOut but I don't know how to put this in my code:

```
function first(){
  sendText("your are not work!");
}
function sendFirst(){
  clearTimeout(time);
  time = setTimeout(first, 5000);
}
```

Could you help me? Thanks

Comment: you mean you want to detect when the field is empty? It's not clear what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want. Will `console.log` 'you are not working!' after 3 seconds of keyboard inactivity. Click 'Run code snippet' below to try it out.

```js
const sendText = console.log;
const input = document.getElementById('fred');

let timeout

const restart = () => {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    sendText("you are not working!");
  }, 3000);
}

restart();

input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  restart();
 if (event.keyCode === 13 && input.value) {
   sendText(input.value);
  // var response = responseChat(input.value, 'user');
  // insertResponse(response);
  input.value = '';
 }
});
```

```html
<input id="fred">
```